# meta_query results not the same with and without spaces

Tags: meta-query

I have a meta_query that gets all the items with a price range between 2 variables. My problem is that 10 000 is not the same as 10000. How can I fix this?

I have been googling but I'n not sure what to google so I'm not really getting anywhere.

Help would be appreciated

Thanks
Hanè

Edit - Code Added

```
    $kw_min = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['kw_min']);
    $kw_max = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['kw_max']);
    $pr_min = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pr_min']);
    $pr_max = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pr_max']);
    if ( !empty( $kw_min ) && !empty( $kw_max ) && !empty( $pr_min ) && !empty( $pr_max ) ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'exc_agriq_equipment', 
            'exc_equipment_cat' => $term->slug,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 12, 
            'paged'=>$paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'exc_agriq_equipment_kw',
                    'value' => array( $kw_min, $kw_max ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'exc_agriq_equipment_price',
                    'value' => array( $pr_min, $pr_max ),
                    'type' => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                ),
              ),
         );
    }
```

Comment: Drop the `mysql_real_escape_string`. All that gets handled via `addslashes` (and its relevants) internally. Question: Where comes the `10 000` vs. `10000` into the game? Is this a search string? How does it get entered? Currently your question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @kaiser: the comments thread is not the appropriate place for providing **answers**... ;)

Comment: I have a search box where I select a custom taxonomy and I can enter a min and max price it gets submitted and then my custom post must be filtered by the custom tax and the meta query. If I enter min price as 10000 and the max price as 20000 I get 0 results but if I enter 10 000 and 20 000 the results show.

Comment: So, this really isn't a **WordPress** question. You're really asking how to sanitize two text strings so that they can be compared.

Comment: Sorry, tried finding an answer before I posted but dint really know what I needed to do and since I'm working with WordPress I just thought to ask here. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Could you please provide examples of stored prices (does it include spaces? why?) and what user input can be (is it just text? can user type in more things other than numbers and space?).

Comment: My current values includes spaces but I have changed it so that you can only input an int. Now I must just find a way to change all my meta_values in the database to int. Any ideas?

Comment: After a good nights rest I updates my database values with `<?php
$con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($database, $con); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM  de2_postmeta  WHERE  meta_key LIKE  'exc_agriq_equipment_price'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$row['meta_value']);
  $key = $row['meta_id'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE de2_postmeta SET meta_value=$price WHERE meta_id=$key");
  }


mysql_close($con);
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing `10000` and `10 000` as **strings**, and as such they are *not the same value*.

So, you either need to sanitize the strings to ensure that both return an equivalent value, or you'll need to force them to be integers, so that they'll be evaluated as the same value.

#### Edit

Your best solution is probably to replace your text form field with a **select**, that includes pre-determined entry values (e.g. 10,000, 20,000, 30,000, etc.). That way, you will have reliable data to use in your `meta_query`.

Comment: That's what I thought but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: How are the values being input? Don't you have control over that?

Comment: Because the value is a price I prefer to add it as 10 000 (easier to read) but if someone is doing a search they wont put the space. I have a custom meta box with custom field price and then just an input field on my search form. Hope that helps

Comment: See updated answer. I would recommend replacing your text entry field with a select, so that you can pre-define, and thus control, the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "10 000" is not the same as "10000". "10 000" isn't even a number, strictly speaking, as a space is not a digit. In PHP, `(int)"10 000"` returns `10` so you can't even force it reliably. WordPress's `absint` does the same. There may be a built-in function that will handle that in a human-like way but I'd have to look around for it.

I would recommend normalizing your data as it goes into the database, as it is inserted, so that you don't have to do any data manipulation as you are trying to retrieve the information. That is, figure out what your data should look like and make sure it fits before you insert it. If your prices are numbers, as I assume they are, check your data for anything that isn't a digit and either reject it (if you are paranoid) or remove everything that isn't a digit, then insert that. Something like...

`$price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',"$price");`

Now when you need to search you know what your format is and you can do the same thing to any user supplied string before you send it to the database query, or reject data that doesn't match (if you are paranoid, which I usually am, by the way). That should get you much more reliable results.

You can use [MySQL's `REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) when you retrieve the data but I don't think you can do that using core functions, unless you start messing with query filters, but that is really the backwards to do it.

Comment: I will give this a try. Is there away to do this and make my values 1 000, 10 000 , 100 000 and 1 000 000? Or am I asking to much?

Comment: You can do that, but do that when you display. Keep things clean in the DB. Try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: Cool this works, now I just need to update my whole database. What would you recommend to change all the values in my database?

Answer (score 0):

### Preparing prices

WP has some stuff built in, as well as PHP has. The really tricky stuff is to regard all possible user behavior. You won't catch everything, but you can catch *alot*, like unintentional white spaces, currency signs, etc. The function below is well commented and will show you how I think the user experience can be made better. I assume that your users will have a similar language as the one set in your CMS.

```
/**
 * Convert a number to a price, formatted according to the blogs
 * currency (which is the value returned by the WPLANG constant)
 * 
 * @param  unknown_type $price 
 * @return integer      $price
 */
function wpse73492_validate_price( $price )
{
    global $wp_locale;

    // Avoid wrong user input: The decimals can only be an integer, no float or string
    $decimals = absint( $decimals );

    // Users might add leading/trailing white space:
    $price = trim( $price );

    // Users might use a lot of funky things in the search
    // Example "shoes 10000" - they simply don't know better
    // But: We allow a decimal point and the thousands separator
    $regex = sprintf( 
         "0-9"
        ,$wp_locale->number_format['decimal_point']
        ,$wp_locale->number_format['thousands_sep']
    );
    preg_replace( "/[^{$regex}]/i", "", $string );

    // Lets convert it to a "money unit"
    // A "money unit" is something extremely different in a lot of contries.
    // Let's take that behavior into account
    // First we need to set the local and the charset: "en_EN.UTF-8"
    setlocale( 
         LC_MONETARY
        ,sprintf(
             '%s.%s'
            ,get_locale()
            ,get_bloginfo( 'charset' )
    );
    // Second, we need to convert it to local currency
    // The WP function is a wrapper for the PHP fn `number_format()`
    // The 2nd argument defines the number of decimals, which should be 0
    // This cares about removing every part that is no absolute integer, but a float.
    $price = number_format_i18n( $price, 0 );

    // Now we need some more funkieness:
    // The DB isn't Babylon. Chinese and such is of our way
    // Remove the thousands separator
    $price = str_replace( $wp_locale->number_format['thousands_sep'], '', $price );

    // Last, we help the DB, and talk to it English
    // This means that we need to get rid of ALOT: Everything non-numeric
    preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/i", "", $string );

    // Just to be sure, we then go and make it an absolute integer
    return absint( $price );
}
```

Then simply run the function on all needed values.

```
// Call it like this:
wpse73492_validate_price( $_GET['pr_max'] );

// Or: If you're sure you got nothing than prices from $_GET
// (Hint: If you got other stuff, you can extract it up front)
$prices = array_map( 'wpse73492_validate_price', $_GET );
```